# Who were the attackers attacked on Amarendra Bahubali when Kattappa killed him?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, baahubali-2-the-conclusion

I'm talking about one scene of [*Bāhubali 2: The Conclusion*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4849438/). Let me introduce that scene. When Kattappa was made convinced to kill Amarendra Bāhubali, one person went to Amarendra Bāhubali and told that Kattappa is being punished on the basis of Rāja-Droha(insurgency). After Amarendra Bāhubali saved Kattappa, some fighters attacked them and we all know during (fight is going to finish though) the fight, Kattappa killed Amarendra Bāhubali.

I want to know who are those attackers? Are they men of Bhallāla Deva i.e., was this fight planned by Bhallāla Deva? I'm asking this because according to scene, after some time, Bhallāla comes and says Kattappa that I suspected you only in vain. You're actually obeyer of mine.

So, I think it might be attackers planned by Bhallāla Deva to kill Amarendra Bāhubali if Kattappa doesn't accomplish his duty of killing but simultaneously looking at the appearances/dresses of fighters, they looked like attackers of other kingdom or not the men of Bhallāla.

So, I can't exactly judge or identify who are the attackers attacked on Amarendra Bāhubali and Kattappa when Kattappa killed Amarendra Bāhubali.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to know who are those attackers?

They are Kalakeya, who Amrendra and Bhallaldeva fought war with in last movie. Their leader was the brother of Kalkeya chief who apparently was killed by Bhallaldeva in last movie.

This role was played by [Charandeep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charandeep).

According to [this](http://www.tollywood.net/topstories/Charan-Deep-as-Kalakeyas-brother-in-Baahubali-2), [this](http://www.gulte.com/movienews/45492/He-Is-Kalakeyas-Brother-In-Baahubali-2) and [this](http://www.chitramala.in/he-is-kalakeyas-brother-in-baahubali-2-214250.html),

> Charandeeep will be playing a full-length character in Part 2, and his clash with Prabhas will be epic, said unit members. Charan Deep revealed that he would start shooting for second part.

For your other question

> Are they men of Bhallāla Deva i.e., was this fight planned by Bhallāla Deva?

Given that Bhallaldeva has fought the war and killed many Kalkeyas, they couldn't be his men nor this fight was planned by him. They appeared to be attacking Maahismati, but Amrendra and Kattappa prevented it. When every Kalkeya was killed, Kattappa killed him too.

For your doubt about Kattappa being obeyer of Bhallaldeva, Bhallaldeva wasn't the king at the time when Bijjaldeva asked him to murder his mother. Kattappa obeyed Shivagami Devi and he was called obeyer(*paaltu kutta* (pet dog) in Hindi) of *Rajmata*. When Bhallaldeva became the king, he had to obey him and therefore murdered Amrendra on his order. That's why Bhallaldeva said that *Tu mera hi kutta hai* (you're obeyer of mine).